# My lettuce leaves keep losing their green color

Tags: hydroponic, lettuce

I transplanted my lettuce to a self-built indoor aeroponics system, about two weeks ago. They seem to be showing slower growth and now & then some of the leaves lose their green color (See the attached image).

I am using general purpose hydroponic nutrients (3 packets: Epsom salt, CaNo3 and one another mix with a lot of things).

Can someone please help me figure out the problem?

I am new to growing plants, so apologies if I am making some stupid mistake.

EDIT: Water flows for 15 mins., after every 30 mins.

[image: Lettuce leaves losing color]